# XSLT with &lt; character in the XML document

Tags: xml, xslt

For the sample data on https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex3

If we change the artist from `<artist>Bob Dylan</artist>` to `<artist>Bob &gt; Dylan</artist>`, the XSLT is able to output the correct symbol. When replacing it with `<artist>Bob &lt; Dylan</artist>`, it results in an error because it seems to treat the `&lt;` as a tag start for the XML. However, when replacing `&lt;` with `&amplt;`, this appears to work fine.

While this is great, it doesn't work for my use case because we have HTML that is embedded in, which we should not escape, e.g. `<artist>&lt;b&gt;Bob&lt;/b&gt; &lt; Dylan</artist>`. It seems using `<xsl:value-of select="artist" disable-output-escaping="yes" />` does not help either.

The same idea applies to this where `<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="string('cd&gt;ab')"/>` works but `<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="string('ab&lt;cd')"/>` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a bug in the w3schools XSLT fiddle website.

Try it on a [better XSLT fiddle website](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%221.0%22%0Axmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Chtml%3E%0A%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch2%3EMy%20CD%20Collection%3C%2Fh2%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20border%3D%221%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%20bgcolor%3D%22%239acd32%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3ETitle%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3EArtist%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each%20select%3D%22catalog%2Fcd%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22title%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22artist%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A%0A&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Ccatalog%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EEmpire%20Burlesque%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EBob%20%26lt%3B%20Dylan%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUSA%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EColumbia%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E10.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1985%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EHide%20your%20heart%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EBonnie%20Tyler%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3ECBS%20Records%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E9.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1988%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EGreatest%20Hits%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EDolly%20Parton%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUSA%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3ERCA%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E9.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1982%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EStill%20got%20the%20blues%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EGary%20Moore%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EVirgin%20records%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E10.20%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1990%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EEros%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EEros%20Ramazzotti%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EEU%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EBMG%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E9.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1997%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EOne%20night%20only%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EBee%20Gees%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EPolydor%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E10.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1998%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ESylvias%20Mother%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EDr.Hook%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3ECBS%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E8.10%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1973%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EMaggie%20May%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3ERod%20Stewart%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EPickwick%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E8.50%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1990%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ERomanza%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EAndrea%20Bocelli%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EEU%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EPolydor%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E10.80%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1996%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EWhen%20a%20man%20loves%20a%20woman%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EPercy%20Sledge%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUSA%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EAtlantic%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E8.70%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1987%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EBlack%20angel%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3ESavage%20Rose%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EEU%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EMega%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E10.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1995%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3E1999%20Grammy%20Nominees%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EMany%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUSA%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EGrammy%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E10.20%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1999%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EFor%20the%20good%20times%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EKenny%20Rogers%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EMucik%20Master%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E8.70%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1995%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EBig%20Willie%20style%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EWill%20Smith%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUSA%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EColumbia%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E9.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1997%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ETupelo%20Honey%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EVan%20Morrison%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EPolydor%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E8.20%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1971%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ESoulsville%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EJorn%20Hoel%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3ENorway%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EWEA%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E7.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1996%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EThe%20very%20best%20of%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3ECat%20Stevens%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EIsland%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E8.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1990%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EStop%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3ESam%20Brown%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EA%20and%20M%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E8.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1988%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EBridge%20of%20Spies%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3ET%60Pau%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3ESiren%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E7.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1987%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EPrivate%20Dancer%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3ETina%20Turner%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3ECapitol%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E8.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1983%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EMidt%20om%20natten%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EKim%20Larsen%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EEU%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EMedley%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E7.80%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1983%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EPavarotti%20Gala%20Concert%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3ELuciano%20Pavarotti%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EDECCA%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E9.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1991%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EThe%20dock%20of%20the%20bay%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EOtis%20Redding%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUSA%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EStax%20Records%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E7.90%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1968%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EPicture%20book%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3ESimply%20Red%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EEU%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EElektra%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E7.20%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1985%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ERed%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EThe%20Communards%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3ELondon%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E7.80%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1987%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EUnchain%20my%20heart%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cartist%3EJoe%20Cocker%3C%2Fartist%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccountry%3EUSA%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3EEMI%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E8.20%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cyear%3E1987%3C%2Fyear%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fcd%3E%0A%3C%2Fcatalog%3E%0A%0A&input-type=XML)

Also, `disable-output-escaping` is a hack and should not be used except in the direst circumstances.